# Site login and session management

Tags: php, session, cookies

So I am working on a site that requires a login against an MySQL database with "remember me" functionality.  I got that fine (based off of Jaspan's page).  What I am a little fuzzy on is the use of sessions to track user movement.  I'm not worried about their history on the site.  I've looked around on the interwebs and especially SO, but I haven't really found what I'm looking for.  Perhaps I'm just not using the right keywords to search.  Anyway... as I said, I have the actual login process, and a cookie is set up with the triplet for the "remember me" functionality.  But how do I track the authenticated status while the user is browsing the website?  The logged-in user should be able to browse the secure area of the website, or the scripts should output special data, without the website having to check the "remember me" triplet against the database every page load.  I thought to do something like $_SESSION['authed']==true, and every page load would check the session value, but I suspect that isn't a very secure way to go about this.  I have observed that if I set $_SESSION['authed']==true, close the browser, open the browser, and go to the site again, it still says authed=true.  Now, I DO understand that the session variables are stored on the webserver, not in the browser's cache.  However, I can't see the big picture enough to know the right way to go about this.

Comment: I want to look on the Interwebs as well!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought to do something like `$_SESSION['authed']==true`, and every page load would check the session value

Yes, that's what you do.

> but I suspect that isn't a very secure way to go about this

It's perfectly fine. You establish a session, which means you send a unique cookie to the user. That is your security. The fact that you have a session at all is your security. Then you simply record the fact whether the user is "logged in" or not in that session.

> I have observed that if I set `$_SESSION['authed']==true`, close the browser, open the browser, and go to the site again, it still says authed=true.

Yes, cookies don't necessarily expire when the browser is closed. Each cookie has a specified expiration time, they can persist however long you want. Even cookies without an expiration time aren't necessarily immediately discarded when the browser is closed. That may have been the default behaviour of browsers a few years ago, but isn't necessarily true anymore.